# Meaning of adding API_EXPORTED with a c function

Tags: c, api

I am using a library and there are some functions before which I have to add `API_EXPORTED` as given in documentation.

Like:

```
API_EXPORTED int fpi_img_compare_print_data(struct fp_print_data
*enrolled_print,        struct fp_print_data *new_print)
```

I dont know what is the use of this keyword.

Comment: It isn't a keyword.  It'll be `#define`d to different values for different platforms somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library seems to be libfprint in which `API_EXPORTED` is a macro defined as:

```
#define API_EXPORTED __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

which would enable the API (e.g. `fpi_img_compare_print_data`) to be made public.

Answer (score 1):

The `API_EXPORTED` symbol is a macro defined using #define in one of the header files related to the library you use.

When you are using that header file to import the library, the macro will likely evaluate to `__declspec(dllimport)`. When the header file is used to build the library the macro will likely evaluate to `__declspec(dllexport)`. You can see for yourself by studying the header file.